# Is it possible to perform regex based string replacement inside a VTL resolver?

Tags: regex, velocity, aws-appsync, vtl

I want to define a Response Mapping Template as follows:

```
#set( $postIds = [] )
#foreach( $item in $ctx.result.items )
    #if( !$util.isNull($item))
        $util.qr($postIds.add($item.SK.replace("^([0-9]){1,}-", "")))
    #end
#end

{
    "items": $utils.toJson($postIds),
    #if( ${context.result.nextToken} )
    "nextToken": "${context.result.nextToken}",
    #end
}
```

The goal is to remove a timestamp followed by a "-" character at the beginning of the SK property of every item.

I checked that the Regex was correct, but this does not seem to work because the digits at the beginning are not removed.

Also tried with `...replace(/^([0-9]){1,}-/", "")`.

If I remember correclty, the documentation says somewhere that all Java string methods are available.

What am i doing incorrectly here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace **regex** use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Or `replaceFirst`

Make sure `SK` is String or use `toString()`